# Need to add signatures to plutus-simple-model-transaction

Tags: plutus, transaction, unit-test

Any idea how to sign a transaction with multiple keys in `plutus-simple-model` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that [source code](https://github.com/mlabs-haskell/plutus-simple-model/blob/f99398b317f2e9d35131178eadcec0fae11a7169/psm/src/Plutus/Model/Mock.hs#L428) just adds signature to the `txSignatures` map, you can call your `signTx` method multiple times for your different keys followed by `sendTx` to submit this transaction.